# Need help converting a string to a char in c++ ---- ERROR A value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"

Tags: c++, string, char, c-strings

```
    bool isValidPrice(string s) 
{
    char c = s.c_str();
    return true;
}
```

I am trying to convert string s into a char but I recieve the error

> A value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"

How would I successfully convert string s into char c?

EDIT****
I want to put each individual char from string and convert the entire string into a c-string so I can use cctype to use c-string functions.

Comment: What do you actually need to do? A char is a single character. So `char c = s[0];` for example is valid to get the first character of the string. But to use `c_str` would be `const char *c = s.c_str();`

Comment: I want to put each individual char from string and convert it into a c-string

Answer (score 2):

you can not load a char (8-bit usually) which is a value, with a pointer (32-bit or 64-bit depending upon your config) which is an address(*s.c_str() returns starting address of the string*). If you want to extract certain character from string, say one at index 0, you can do:

```
char c = s[0];
```

Assuming string s is not empty

Comment: This is a pretty good answer to the question, but I think it could be more clear what you mean by "which is an address" — where did the address come from? Would recommend [edit]ing to add some clarity :)

Comment: @ jtbandes: explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

From the method name I understood that you want to validate of a product's price. But this code isn't something to check. Because if `s = "&"` then your code return true which should be false. Also you are checking only the first character. Is it right? I am assuming that you will be given in a valid integer format.

```
bool isValidPrice(string s) 
{
    if(s.length() == 0) 
        return false;

    char c = s[0];
    return true;
}
```